# Total Least Squares regression for a quadratic function

Tags: algorithms, regression, least-squares

I have a set of points $(x_i,y_i),\ i=1,\ldots,n$ and want to find a quadratic function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, at the end I need to find $a,b,c$, which has shortest distances to the set of points.

So, the condition is to find $a, b, c$ which do minimize the function
$P(a,b,c,x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n(d^2_i)$,
where $d_i^2=(\hat x_i -x_i)^2 + (\hat y_i -y_i)^2$ is the distance from point $(x_i,y_i)$ to the parabola $f(x)$.
and point $(\hat x_i, \hat y_i)$ is the point on the parabola $f(x)$, which has the shortest distance to the point $(x_i,y_i)$

[image: TLSPicture]

I could constitute formulas for $a,b,c$ for **OLS(ordinary least squares)** dependent only from $x_i, y_i$ because I had to find a minimum on function $P(a,b,c)$, so it was enough to take a derivative on $a$, $b$, and $c$ and so solve system of three equation with three unknown.

For **TLS(total least squares)** regression, I think the same is orthogonal regression see [Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression),  the function $P(a,b,c)$ does also depend on unknown $\hat x_i$, which is the $x$ coordinate of the point on the parabola nearest to the point$(x_i,y_i)$.
In the internet I could unfortunately only find formulas for TLS regression for the line $f(x)=ax+b$, but not for parabola.
At the moment I stuck to get the formulas for $a,b,c$ dependent only on $(x_i,y_i)$

**What are the formulas (like $a=\sum(x^2_i)+ \sum(y^2_i)$ etc.)** and how can I find them.

To understand clearer what I want, here are the formulas for $a$, $b$ and $c$ using **OLS** regression(they can definitely be simplified, but I had too few time, all $\sum$ are $\sum_{i=1}^n$):

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid darkblue]
{
\mathbf b = \frac{n \sum (x^2y) - \sum x^2 \sum y + (\sum x^2)^2(M-L) - n(M-L)\sum x^4}{n\sum x^3} / (1 - \frac{E(\sum x^2)^2 - \sum x^2 \sum x}{n\sum X^3} + \frac{E\sum x^4}{\sum x^3})
}$$
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid darkblue]
{
\mathbf a = b*E + M - L
}$$
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid darkblue]
{
\mathbf c = \frac{\sum y - a \sum x^2 - b \sum x}{n}
}$$

$E = \frac{(\sum x^2)^2 -n \sum x^2}{n\sum x^3 - \sum x^2 \sum x}$

$M = \frac{n\sum (xy)}{n\sum x^3 - \sum x^2 \sum x}$

$L = \frac{\sum x \sum y}{n\sum x^3 - \sum x^2 \sum x}$

Comment: Are both x and y subject to uncertainty or just y?

Comment: @Paul Since `a, b, c` are unknown, the points on parabola, which have shortest distance are also uncertain, both x and y, or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: The $x_i$ values might be known (e.g fixed time intervals) and the $y_i$  measurements taken at those x values but subject to error. Then normal least squares is appropriate. Are you saying that your $x_i$ values are also subject to error?

Comment: You ask the questions.. :) I would say, yes, the $x$ is also subject to error, so the OLS gives not well enough fitting of the curve to the set of points.

Comment: Do you need the actual derivations or a general solver?

Comment: @Royi First of all I need the formulas, to find $\mathbf a$ , $\mathbf b$ and $\mathbf c$. How to get them is interesting, but not necessary. These formulas are thought to be used in a program library, where the input will be a set of points.

Comment: There is a more general way to solve Total Least Squares with SVD. It will work with more variables and will be more robust. It is few lines of MATLAB code for that matter.

Comment: I will do it in C#, so there are no libraries such as in matlab or in excel, or rather I want to write such a library in C# by myself.

Answer (score 2):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Calculations of the distance.}}$

The square of the distance from the point $\;(X,Y)\;$ of the given set $(X_i,Y_i)$ to the parabola $\,(a,s,v) = a(x-s)^2+v = \pm z^2+v\;$ is
$$d^2 =  \min\limits_{x\in\mathbb R} \delta(x),$$
where $\;x\;$ is the abscissa of the arbitrary point on the parabola,
$$z = \sqrt{|a|}\,(x-s),\quad Z =\sqrt{|a|}\,(X-s).\tag1$$
$$\delta(x) = f(z) = (z-Z)^2+(z^2\pm(v-Y))^2,\tag2$$
$$\dfrac12f'(z) = z-Z+2z(z^2\pm(v-Y)),\tag3$$
If to denote abscissa of the optimal point on the parabola as $\;\hat x,\;$ and $\;\hat z= \sqrt{|a|}\,(\hat x-s),\;$ then
$$\begin{cases}
2\hat z^3+(1\pm2(v-Y))\hat z=Z\\[4pt]
d^2= (\hat z-Z)^2+(\hat z^2\pm(v-Y))^2.
\end{cases}\tag4$$
From $(4)$ should
$$d^2\in\big[0,(Z^2\pm(v-Y)^2)^2\big],\tag5$$
$$2d^2 = 2(\hat z- Z)^2 +Z\hat z+2(v-Y)^2\big(2\hat z^2\pm(v-Y))^2-(1\pm2(v-Y))\big)\hat z^2,$$
$$2d^2 = (1\mp2(v-Y)+4(v-Y)^2)\hat z^2 -3 Z\hat z+2Z^2\pm2(v-Y)^4,$$
$$d^2 = p\left(\hat z - \dfrac{3Z}{2p}\right)^2+\dfrac{8p-9}{8p}\,Z^2\pm(v-Y)^4,\tag{6.1}$$
where
$$p = 1\mp2(v-Y)+4(v-Y)^2\tag{6.2}$$
Formulas $(5)-(6)$ can simplify the calculations.

Let
$$r=\sqrt{\dfrac{|2\pm 4(v-Y)|}{3}}.\tag7$$

If $\;\mathbf{1\pm2(v-Y) \ge 0},\;$ then
$$4\hat z^3+3r^2\hat z = 2Z,$$
$$\dfrac{2Z}{r^3} = 4\left(\dfrac{\hat z}r\right)^3 + 3\dfrac{\hat z}r
=\sinh\left(3\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{\hat z}r\right),$$
$$\hat z = r\sinh\left(\dfrac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{2Z}{r^3}\right).\tag{8.1}$$

If $\;\mathbf{1\pm2(v-Y) \le 0},\;$ then
$$4\hat z^2-3r^2\hat z = 2Z,$$
$$\dfrac{2Z}{r^3} = 4\left(\dfrac{\hat z}r\right)^3 - 3\dfrac{\hat z}r
=-\sin\left(3\arcsin\dfrac{\hat z}r\right)
=\cosh\left(3\operatorname{arccosh}\dfrac{\hat z}r\right),$$
$$\hat z = \begin{cases}
-r\sin\left(\dfrac13\arcsin\dfrac{2Z}{r^3}\right),\quad\text{if}\quad 2|Z|\le r^3\\[4pt]
r\cosh\left(\dfrac13\operatorname{arccosh}\dfrac{2Z}{r^3}\right),\quad\text{if}\quad 2|Z|\ge r^3
\end{cases}\tag{8.2}$$
On the other hand, the cubic equations
$$\hat z^3\pm\dfrac34\,r^2\hat z -\dfrac Z2 = 0$$
have the discriminants
$$D = \dfrac{Z^2}{16}\pm\dfrac{r^6}{64},\tag9$$
wherein

- if $\;D>0,\;$ then the single solution can be obtained by the Cardano's formula;
- if $\;D\le 0\;\Rightarrow (a<0)\wedge(2|Z|\le r^3),\;$ then there are three real roots, which satisfy the equation
  $$\dfrac{2Z}{r^3} = 4\left(\dfrac{\hat z}r\right)^3 - 3\dfrac{\hat z}r
  =\cos\left(3\arccos\dfrac{\hat z}r\right).$$
  Therefore, the most accurate solution of cubic is
  $$\hat z =r\begin{cases}
  \sqrt[\large3]{-\dfrac Z4+\sqrt D}+\sqrt[\large3]{-\dfrac Z4-\sqrt D},\;\text{if}\; D>0\\[4pt]
  r\cos\left(\dfrac{2k\pi}3+\dfrac13\arccos\dfrac{2Z}{r^3}\right), \;\text{otherwize}.
  \end{cases}\tag{10}$$
  Parameter $\;k=-1,0,+1\;$ should minimize the distance square $(4.1)$ or $(6.1)$ under the condiion $(5).$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{How does it work?}}$

If
$$\binom{X_i}{Y_i}=\left\{\dbinom11,\dbinom22, \dbinom34, \dbinom48, \dbinom5{13}\right\},$$
$$y=\dfrac12x^2+v,$$
[image: The task a=1/2 standing]

then for $\;Z_i=\sqrt2\,X_i\;$ formulas $(8.1)$ allow to get quite realistic plot $\;\hat z_i(v) = \sqrt2 \hat X_i\;$
[image: The task a=1/2, hat z(v)]

If
$$\binom{X_i}{Y_i}=\left\{\dbinom1{15},\dbinom2{14}, \dbinom3{12}, \dbinom48, \dbinom5{3}\right\},$$
$$y=-\dfrac12x^2+v,$$
[image: The task a=-1/2 standing]

then for $\;Z_i=\sqrt2\,X_i\;$ formulas $(10.2)$ over the complex numbers allow to get quite understandable plots $\;\hat z_i(v) = \sqrt2 \hat X_i\;$ with $\;k=0, -1, 1\;$

[image: The task a=-1/2, k=0, hat z(v)]
[image: The task a=-1/2, k=-1, hat z(v)]
[image: The task a=-1/2, k=1, hat z(v)]

To get the parabola parameters, it suffices to use the method of the volumes. Every elementary volume should provide the next conditions:

- the sign of $\;a\;$ should be hold (the case $\;a=0\;$ can be used for training);
- the signs of $\;1\pm 2(v-Y)\;$ should be hold at the all given points;
- the signs of $r^3-2|Z|$ should be hold at the all given points, where $\;1\pm2(v-Y)<0.\;$

Under these conditions, the constant expression of the sums of the squares of the distances should be defined in the each elementary volume of $\;(a,v,s).\;$

Obtained formulas allow to minimize the sums of the distances squares in the every elementary volume (gradient descent recommended) and then to provide the least of them.

Comment: Yuri, what is $a$, $s$ and $v$ in the distance formula?

Comment: @Rekshino Parabola via vertex coordinates $\;(s,v).\;$ Looks more usable and can be easily transformed to the common polynomial form. Thanks!

Comment: Is $Z$ the $\hat X$ in my notation?

Comment: @Rekshino Thank you for the comment, notation is detalized.

Comment: Can you explain the second part of `(4)`, is it also another form of distance ;) ? Usually $d^2= (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2$.

Comment: @Rekshino Okay, simplified

Comment: I have awarded the answer with bounty(a lot of work was done), but still can not accept it, because I don't see the formulas for $a, b, c$ or $a, s, v$ in your notation dependent only on $X_i,Y_i$.

Comment: @Rekshino Sadly, explicit solutions does not exist.

Comment: Negometjanov Sure?

Comment: @Rekshino Yes. We have non-linear system on the coefficients, and there is a critical difference, even relatively the LS for the linear combination of the arbitrary functions.